# Splitting Vuex module into multiple files in the same namespace

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

I am trying to split my Vuex module into chunks. In addition to creating multiple namespaced modules (`namespaced: true`), I want to extend the global module that became extremely long. It seems that in some cases, it is preferred to keep some of my actions/mutations in the global module, as they communicate with each other and are too coupled, but using `{ root: true }` option each time I need to execute an action or mutation is not feeling good enough in my opinion. So, in my case, not setting `namespaced` to `true` sounds like the perfect solution.

But...

First of all - it seems like not-namespaced modules can't hold their own `state`.
Moreover - when they try to use `state` delivered to the actions/mutations, they fail since they can't communicate with the root state directly (just with `rootState` param, which is not what i was expecting).

One more possible solution I could think of is to init my Vuex store like this:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {
    ...actionsFromFile1,
    ...actionsFromFile2
  }
});
```

But this solution yet doesn't seem the best. Is there any other solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your actions and mutations in your modules.

As you mentioned you can use `root` to dispatch actions of other modules.
Why you should use this, is easy. Visibility - If you need to dispatch an action from another store keep it in the module where you expect it, splitting code into your global store and modules will make it hard to track where things come from.

Also your global store will grow and you will have a hard time finding what you want to later.

simple example:

```
// message.js

const actions = {
  add({ dispatch }, message) {
    dispatch("chat/initializeChat", {}, { root: true });

    // add message or something
  },
};
```

Comment: But the point is that I don't want to move some actions to another module, since they all communicate with each other. Using `{ root: true }` isn't the best solution in such case. Its like any other project structure, where you want to split files into smaller files in case the file gets too long, and splitting isn't necessarily meaning to move it to a different module.

Comment: If you want to stay with your structure you will need to split your global storage functions into smaller files, import them and use them as in your provided example. 

I still wouldn't recommend it :D

Comment: I still try to figure out what you mean by they communicate with each other ? 
can you give an example. :D

Comment: yes. actionfile1 has action named action1, and actionfile2 has an action named action2. action1 dispatches an action, that (let's say) inits an event listener. this event listener dispatches an action from file 1 uppon trigger. it is bound in the 2 ways, but child-to-parent communication is a bad practice in programming, therefore splitting to modules won't help me.

Comment: so you have something like this ?

action1(file1) -> action1(file2) -> action2(file1) 

Putting this into the modules wouldn't be a bad practice at all because you will know where something is done *for the module store itsself* and when another module is called and used/changed. 

This information for any other developer e.g. will be lost in your  implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate files for separate modules: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html